# AzureRM application gateway backend pools - is there a way to specify an App Service instead of FQDNs/IPs?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to create a new Backend Pool in PowerShell.

In Azure's UI, these Backend Pools can refer to an App Service (e.g. a single container).

[image: Azure Backend Pool UI]

The PowerShell cmdlet however doesn't appear to support this, as far as I can see:

```
$AppGw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "ApplicationGateway01" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
$AppGw = Add -AzureApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $ AppGw -Name "Pool02" -BackendIPAddresses "10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"

$AppGw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "ApplicationGateway01" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
$AppGw = Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name "Pool02" -BackendFqdns "contoso1.com", " contoso1.com"
```

I was hoping that it would be something along the lines of...

```
$AppService = Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name 'WebApp01'
$AppGw = Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name 'Pool02' -BackendWebApp $AppService
```

Does anyone know if there's any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PowerShell, it seems there no cmdlet can achieve it that you expected:

```
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name 'Pool02' -BackendWebApp $AppService
```

In the Azure portal, it is just convenient for people to find the App Service with the type App Services and get the FQDN. But for PowerShell cmdlet, it is more direct to input the FQDN.

By the way, people usually use an FQDN to access Azure Web Service. You can get more details about Configure App Service Web Apps with Application Gateway [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app).

Comment: You're right Charles, thank you. I have used the FQDN instead and this is working as I need it to.